# function executed after dismissing a view isn't working completly IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I'm working on an iphone application which requires a code to be inputed by the user.
i have a first viewController which will call my passwordPrompt view controller when user touches a button with -->

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"passcodePrompt" sender:self];
```

the passcode prompte is displayed fine, i can input my password , then when i click ok , the passwordPrompt view is dismissed with -->

```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil];
```

now when i dismiss this view controller , i call a function in my firstViewController from the password prompt controller (i tried using the completion option of dismissViewControllerAnimated and tried calling my function from the viewDidUnload as well)-->

```
    FirstViewController *firstViewControl = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    [firstViewControl returnPass:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",digit1.text,digit2.text,digit3.text,digit4.text]];
```

this function is executed in my FirstViewController fine , but even though it executes those lines of code -->

```
[passButton setTitle:@"Password is Correct" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] deactivateMoveDetection];

infoText.text = @"application unlocked until fully closed by user";

infoText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

passButton.tag = 0;
```

(debugging showed me it did execute those lines without any errors, strange thing is , after executing the function , the debugger takes me back to the function initiating the dismiss in the password prompt controller)

the title is NOT changed , passButton.tag is NOT set to 0 , and the infoText is NOT change neither is his color.

i've been searching for 2 days now without luck. 
thanks for the help

------ passcodePrompt.m -------

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   dig1 = false;
   dig2 = false;
   dig3 = false;
   dig4 = false;
   ok.enabled = false;
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

------- SOLUTION ------

I added to my passcodePrompt.h -->

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *delegate;
```

to be able to set up the firstViewController as delegate of my passcodeprompt with a segueWithIdentifier, I had to add this to my FirstViewcontroller.m -->

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    PasscodePrompt *passprompt = [segue destinationViewController];
    passprompt.delegate = self;
}
```

and from the passwordPrompt.m, I executed my function in FirstViewController with -->

```
[self.delegate returnPass:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",digit1.text,digit2.text,digit3.text,digit4.text]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely in this chunk of code:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewControl = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

[firstViewControl returnPass:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",digit1.text,digit2.text,digit3.text,digit4.text]];
```

You aren't referencing the SAME FistViewController, you are creating a new one. This explains why the method is being called and your breakpoints are being hit, but also why your original view controller is not updated. In this case, you have *TWO UNIQUE* view controllers, the first one is the correct one, and the second one you're updating is a completely new one.

See my answer to this question on how to implement delegation, so your FirstViewController can be the *delegate* of the presented view controller, and before you're about to dismiss the presented view controller it can tell it's delegate (the original FirstViewController) to return the passcode.

[Calling method from viewcontroller to class xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495831/calling-method-from-viewcontroller-to-class-xcode/25495977?noredirect=1#comment39797449_25495977)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , both of you. i followed your answer in the other post , but i'm using
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"passcodePrompt" sender:self];       so i changed it to -->   PasscodePrompt *passprompt = [[PasscodePrompt alloc] init];
            passprompt.delegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:passprompt animated: YES];    to comply with your answer but now , when the view loads, it just apears black , no animation and no content . any idea ?

Comment: What do you have in the passcode prompt view controller's init method?

Comment: the initWithNibName is empty , i never used it so i left it empty (i'll update the question with the code)

Comment: i built the passwordPrompt with storyboard as well , in case it matters

Comment: It is working now :) thanks to your tutorial and an other one which clarified some points . i'll put my solution in the question . Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the first view controller that pushes the password view controller onto the stack...

The password view controller does its thing then dismisses, which returns back to the first view controller...

In your password view controller's dismiss completion block you create another first view controller by simply allocating one and you do a few things on that object...

The first view controller you had displayed before moving to the password view controller is not the same object you allocated (alloc, init) in the completion block that happened to be an object of FirstViewController.

There are multiple ways you can solve this. To keep it simple you can add a delegate object to the password view controller and a set of methods so that before the password view controller dismisses it calls the delegate's method to update the delegate of the new information it needs. The first view controller would be this delegate.

Comment: your answer was good , but as i'm not very familiar with delegates , i upvoted an answer which was more easy for me. thanks anyway, as i did use the delegate methode to solve my problem.

Comment: No worries. Glad you found a solution to your issue.